# Increase text size in table while I use \textwidth in the table

Tags: tables, width, size

I have a table that its width should not be larger than 0.45 of the textwidth (two column page), but I want to make the table's data larger to better see the Table info. How can I do that?

This is my table LaTeX code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Emission results in CAT-3401 diesel engine in the
part-load operating condition}
\label{emission}
\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{}{}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{HC (kg/kgf)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{NOX (kg/kgf)} \\ \cline{2-6} 
 &  Experiment & Simulation with crevice flow model & simulation Without crevice flow model & Experiment & Simulation \\ \hline
0\% substitution & ~0 & 0.0099 & N/A & 0.3312 & 0.1950 \\ \hline
50\% substitution & 0.703 & 1.4621 & 0.3018 & 0.1542 & 0.1587 \\ \hline
75\% substitution & 1.73 & 2.3291 & 0.9824 & 0.087 & 0.0886 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table in original size and organization is to wide to be fit into text and its shrinking to column width cause unreadable small fonts, so me on your place would looking how to reformat table ...

See, if my table redesign can help you:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\caption{Emission results in CAT-3401 diesel engine in the
part-load operating condition}
    \label{emission}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}c L *{3}{S[table-format=1.4]}@{}}
    \toprule
    &               &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{substitution}        \\
    \cmidrule{3-5}
    &               &   {\SI{0}{\%}} 
                                &   {\SI{50}{\%}}
                                            &   {\SI{75}{\%}}   \\ 
    \midrule
\multirow{3}{11mm}{HC (kg/kgf)}
    &   Experiment  &   0       &   0.0099  &   {N/A}           \\  
    &   Simulation with CVM\textsuperscript{*}
                    &   0.703   &   1.4621  &   0.3018          \\
    &   Simulation without CVM\textsuperscript{*}
                    &   1.73    &   2.3291  &   0.9824          \\
    \midrule
\multirow{2}{11mm}{NOX (kg/kgf)}
    &   Experiment  &   0.3312  &   0.1542  &   0.087           \\     
    &   Simulation  &   0.1950  &   0.1587  &   0.0886          \\    
    \midrule[1pt]
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textsuperscript{*} CFM: Crevice Flow Model}
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, I transform your table: your columns are now rows. By this more space for before columns heads are available. I also suggest to introduce shortens for `Crevice Flow Model`. With all this hacks table can be fit in column width with `\footnotesize` fonts. If you agree with two line text in cells with `Simulation with CVM\textsuperscript{*}` and `Simulation without CVM\textsuperscript{*}`, than you can use normal size fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Zarko solution is nice (+1), this is only another more lazy way to not transpose the table. In any case ... always is better redesign that resizing!

---

[image]

---

In two columns texts, often a elegant solution for a  table wider than one column is use `table*` (with `*`)  to place the table centered in the two-columns at the top of the next page. If it could be as wide as two columns,  instead of  center  `tabular`,  use  `tabular*` (with `*`) or `tabularx` or `tabulary` two expand it exactly to both margins.

When  this is not enough, think in redesign the table. Notes in caption or footnotes are good alternatives to verbose headings.

Of course, always without vertical rules and well spaces  horizontal rules from `booktabs` and better with decimal alignment with  `siunitx` or `dcolumn`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabulary,lipsum}
\usepackage{dcolumn,tipa}
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{6.6}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\caption{Emission results in CAT-3401 diesel engine 
in the part-load operating condition}
\label{emission}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\kern -1ex}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l*{5}{d}}
\toprule  & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{HC (kg/kgf)} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{NOX (kg/kgf)}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-6}  &  
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Experiment} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Simulation\footnote{~With crevice flow model}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Simulation\footnote{~Without crevice flow model}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Experiment} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Simulation} \\\midrule 
0\% substitution & ~0 & 0.0099 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N/A} & 0.3312 & 0.1950 \\ 
50\% substitution & 0.703 & 1.4621 & 0.3018 & 0.1542 & 0.1587 \\ 
75\% substitution & 1.73 & 2.3291 & 0.9824 & 0.087 & 0.0886 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}%
\end{minipage}
\end{table*}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

Comment: ... of course, spanning table over two columns ... (+1). Nice design and good description.